# save data from Excel to SQL database table where the table name is based on a cell in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have this code in my excel VBA

```
cnn.Execute "insert into dbo.DelTrans2 (DATE, SOURCE, DESTINATION, REFERENCE#, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, UM, PRICE, QTY, AMOUNT, MFG, EXP, LOT, TRANS, CONSIGNOR, DRDATE) values ('" & qDATE & "','" & qSOURCE & "','" & qDESTINATION & "','" & qREFERENCE & "','" & qItemCode & "','" & qDescription & "','" & qUM & "','" & qPRICE & "','" & qQTY & "','" & qAMT & "','" & qMFG & "','" & qEXP & "','" & qLOT & "','" & qTRANSACTION & "','" & qConsignor & "','" & qDRDATE & "')"
```

where the dbo.DelTrans2 is  the name of the table where the data will be saved, I want to know if it is possible to change the dbo.DelTrans2 depending on what a certain cell has.

Comment: You've left yourself so vulnerable to SQL injection now that it won't make things any worse to dynamically concatenate a cell value into your SQL statement. `cnn.Execute "Insert into " & Range("A1").Value & " (DATE...)"`. Don't be surprised when your data is exposed/deleted/corrupted by a malicious user, though. (If you're not sure why, Google *Little Bobby Tables*.)

Comment: Thank you! and yes I am aware of that, the set of computers are n a separate network where no one is connected to the internet, unless one of the users try to do that in that same network...

Comment: Doesn't have to be the internet. Imagine the worker who feels they've been treated badly, or knows they're about to be fired or laid off, or that has a new job offer from a competitor. Data loss or corruption or breach is the same no matter what causes it.

Comment: I just hope no one will do that, by the way, thanks for your answer, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've left yourself so vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) now that it won't make things any worse to dynamically concatenate a cell value into your SQL statement. Don't be surprised when your data is exposed/deleted/corrupted by a malicious user, though. (If you're not sure why, meet [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).)

```
cnn.Execute "insert into " & .Range("A1").Value & " dbo.DelTrans2 (DATE, SOURCE, DESTINATION, REFERENCE#, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, UM, PRICE, QTY, AMOUNT, MFG, EXP, LOT, TRANS, CONSIGNOR, DRDATE) values ('" & qDATE & "','" & qSOURCE & "','" & qDESTINATION & "','" & qREFERENCE & "','" & qItemCode & "','" & qDescription & "','" & qUM & "','" & qPRICE & "','" & qQTY & "','" & qAMT & "','" & qMFG & "','" & qEXP & "','" & qLOT & "','" & qTRANSACTION & "','" & qConsignor & "','" & qDRDATE & "')"
```